# Convert hours:minutes to seconds where hours > 24

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a string 47:45.
That means 47 hours, 45 minutes.
I want to convert that string to seconds.

> select datediff(second, '00:00','47:45') <-- does not work

what is the quickest way to find the 171.900 seconds I am looking for?

Comment: Why not just https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html then https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_NUMBER.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OPERATOR_SYMBOLS.html with 3600 and 60?

Comment: I do realise that is a way to do it. It is a lot of calculating though. I was hoping to avoid that. Am wondering if there is a quicker way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would by delimiting the semicolon separated values and multiplying the minutes part by 60 and hours by 3600 and adding the result.
Thanks!